# Error Code: 1064 | Delimiter

Tags: mysql, delimiter

DELIMITER $$

```
ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `v_t_buku_bank` AS 
SELECT
  `b`.`id`                 AS `id`,
  `b`.`no_bku`             AS `no_bku`,
  `b`.`tanggal`            AS `tanggal`,
  `b`.`tanggal_bayar`      AS `tanggal_bayar`,
  `b`.`id_transaksi_bank`  AS `id_transaksi_bank`,
  `b`.`no_bukti`           AS `no_bukti`,
  `b`.`jumlah`             AS `jumlah`,
  `b`.`id_akun_pendapatan` AS `id_akun_pendapatan`,
  `ap`.`kode`              AS `pendapatan_kode`,
  `m`.`jenis`              AS `jenis`,
  `m`.`nama`               AS `transaksi`,
  `ap`.`nama`              AS `pendapatan`,
  IF((`m`.`jenis` = 'm'),`b`.`jumlah`,0) AS `masuk`,
  IF((`m`.`jenis` = 'k'),`b`.`jumlah`,0) AS `keluar`
FROM ((`t_buku_bank` `b`
    JOIN `t_master_transaksi_bank` `m`
      ON ((`m`.`id` = `b`.`id_transaksi_bank`)))
   LEFT JOIN `akun_pendapatan` `ap`
     ON ((`ap`.`id` = `b`.`id_akun_pendapatan`)))$$

IF((`b`.`id_transaksi_bank` = '11'),`b`.`jumlah`,0) AS `m11`,
  IF((`b`.`id_transaksi_bank` = '12'),`b`.`jumlah`,0) AS `m12`,
  IF((`b`.`id_transaksi_bank` = '21'),`b`.`jumlah`,0) AS `k21`,
  IF((`b`.`id_transaksi_bank` = '22'),`b`.`jumlah`,0) AS `k22`,
  IF((`b`.`id_transaksi_bank` = '23'),`b`.`jumlah`,0) AS `k23`
FROM (`t_buku_bank` `b`
   JOIN `t_master_transaksi_bank` `tb`
     ON ((`tb`.`id` = `b`.`id_transaksi_bank`)))$$

  DELIMITER ;
```

i got Error Code: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF((`b`.`id_transaksi_bank` = '11'),`b`.`jumlah`,0) AS `m11`,
>   IF((`b`.`id_tran' at line 1

please help me, iam new in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `$$` that break your query:

```
ON ((`ap`.`id` = `b`.`id_akun_pendapatan`)))$$
```

and

```
ON ((`tb`.`id` = `b`.`id_transaksi_bank`)))$$
```

Remove them and try again